# Swift Annotation Pin's Calloutbubble Gesture

Tags: ios, swift

I am searching an answer for adding gesture to the calloutbubble of annotation pin.

I tried different solutions, but they did not work for me.

Here is the latest one:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView{
    let rightButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(callout(gesture:)))
    rightButton.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)   
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton
}

@objc func callout(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("tapped")
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Tap on CalloutBubble in MKAnnotationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395772/detect-tap-on-calloutbubble-in-mkannotationview)

Comment: @chirag90 I said I tried those solutions and they did not WORK for me. thanks anyway..

Comment: what didn't work ? what was issue you got? Just saying it didn't work doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct delegate method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    ///
}
```

plus

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
```